# Question in finding a new $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $F/\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ be the splitting field of $x^4 - 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $G$ be its Galois group. When viewed as a $\mathbb{Q}$- vectorspace, $F$ has the following basis:

$$\mathcal{B}=\{1,2^{1/4},2^{1/2},2^{3/4},i,2^{1/4}i,2^{1/2}i,2^{3/4}i\}$$

According to the Normal Basis Theorem, there exists some $x\in F$ such that the set $\{g(x)|g\in G\}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $F$.

My questions is how we can find such $x\in F$? It seemed natural to me that we start doing something to the basis we already have. But, for example, $x$ definitely cannot be $i$ or $2^{1/4}$, since for any $g\in G$, we must have $g(i)=\pm i$ and $g(2^{1/4})=\pm 2^{1/4}$. For the same reason, if you take some linear combination, for example, $i+ 2^{1/4}$, then $g(i+2^{1/4}) = \pm i \pm 2^{1/4}$. So how should we find such $x$?

Comment: @AlexWertheim I was thinking that let $s$ be the sum of all the basis in $\mathcal{B}$. Then $g(s)$ would be a basis, too. But that seems not to be the case because you would get redundant vectors?

Comment: @Misakov $g(2^{1/4}) = \pm i^k 2^{1/4}$, with $k=0,1$.

Comment: @Misakov However, proving that $\pm i \pm i^k2^{1/4}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ will be another story. The conjugates of a primitive element may not be linearly independent over the base field.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Actually, they all add up to $0$, so they are not linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @i707107: yes, silly me. It is true that $i+2^{1/4}$ generates the extension, and that the powers of $i+2^{1/4}$ form a basis, but this need not be true of the other *roots*, which may be linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$ (as in this case). Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @AlexWertheim So $g(i+ 2^{1/4})$ form a basis but $g(2^{1/4})$ does not. Is that correct?

Comment: @Misakov: no, as pointed out by i707107. The size of the Galois orbit of $i+2^{1/4}$ is $8$, which means $i+2^{1/4}$ generates the extension. However, it does not mean that the elements of the Galois orbit of $i+2^{1/4}$ form a basis for $F/\mathbb{Q}$; indeed, the sum of the elements is $0$. However, with the $s$ you define above, $g(s)$ does generate a normal basis, and the answer by i707107 below proves this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We try applying a method in K. Conrad's note: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/linearchar.pdf

Since $\pm i \pm i^k2^{1/4}$ does not work because they sum to $0$, we modify the choice of $\alpha$ as
$$\alpha= 1+ i + 2^{1/4} + 2^{1/2}+ 2^{3/4}+i 2^{1/4} +i 2^{1/2} + i 2^{3/4}.$$

The Galois group $G\simeq D_{2\times 4}$ is generated by $\sigma$ and $\tau$ satisfying 
$$
\sigma(2^{1/4})= i2^{1/4}, \ \ \sigma(i)=i,$$

$$
\tau(2^{1/4})=2^{1/4}, \ \ \tau(i)=-i,$$
$$
\sigma^4=\tau^2=\mathrm{Id}, \ \ \tau\sigma= \sigma^{-1}\tau.$$

Then we have
$$\alpha= 1+ i + 2^{1/4} + 2^{1/2}+ 2^{3/4}+i 2^{1/4} +i 2^{1/2} + i 2^{3/4},$$
$$
\sigma(\alpha)= 1+i-2^{1/4}-2^{1/2}+2^{3/4}+i2^{1/4}-i2^{1/2}-i2^{3/4}, 
$$
$$\sigma^2(\alpha)=1+i-2^{1/4}+2^{1/2}-2^{3/4}-i2^{1/4}+i2^{1/2}-i2^{3/4},$$
$$\sigma^3(\alpha)=1+i+2^{1/4}-2^{1/2}-2^{3/4}-i2^{1/4}-i2^{1/2}+i2^{3/4},$$
$$\tau(\alpha)=1-i+2^{1/4}+2^{1/2}+2^{3/4}-i2^{1/4}-i2^{1/2}-i2^{3/4},$$
$$\sigma\tau(\alpha)= 1-i+2^{1/4}-2^{1/2}-2^{3/4}+i2^{1/4}+i2^{1/2}-i2^{3/4},$$
$$\sigma^2\tau(\alpha)=1-i-2^{1/4}+2^{1/2}-2^{3/4}+i2^{1/4}-i2^{1/2}+i2^{3/4},$$
$$\sigma^3\tau(\alpha)=1-i-2^{1/4}-2^{1/2}+2^{3/4}-i2^{1/4}+i2^{1/2}+i2^{3/4}.$$

Now, set up a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear relation 
$$
a_1 \alpha + a_2 \sigma(\alpha) + a_3 \sigma^2(\alpha)+ a_4 \sigma^3(\alpha) +a_5 \tau(\alpha) + a_6 \sigma\tau(\alpha) + a_7 \sigma^2\tau(\alpha) + a_8 \sigma^3\tau(\alpha)=0$$
must result in the following linear system over $\mathbb{Q}$. 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 &1 &1 &1 &1& 1& 1& 1 \\ 
1 &1 &1 &1 &-1 &-1 &-1 &-1\\
1 &-1 &-1 &1 &1& 1& -1& -1\\
1 &-1 &1 &-1 &1 &-1 &1 &-1\\
1 &1 &-1 &-1 &1 &-1 &-1 &1\\
1 &1 &-1 &-1 &-1 &1 &1 &-1\\
1 &-1 &1 &-1 &-1 &1 &-1 &1\\
1 &-1 &-1 &1 &-1 &-1 &1 &1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\\a_5\\a_6\\a_7\\a_8\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$

An online matrix determinant calculator: http://comnuan.com/cmnn0100b/ 
gives the determinant of this $8\times 8$ matrix as $-4096$. Thus, the system is nonsingular, and all $a_i$ must thus be all $0$.

Therefore, we see that $\alpha$ generates the normal basis of $\mathbb{Q}(i,2^{1/4})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: +1 Nice answer! From tinkering with this problem, it seems that it is ''harder'' to pick an element which generates the normal basis of a separable extension than it is to find an element which generates the extension, where the primitive element theorem suggests that ''most'' elements will do. Do you know if there is any truth to this heuristic? I suppose I should rigorously define "harder" and "most" above if my question is to make sense... :)

Comment: @AlexWertheim If we find an element which generates the normal basis, the element must be a primitive element (by degree comparison). But, as we saw, it may not be the other way around.

Comment: If you want to avoid the reference to online calculator you can simply observe that the rows of your 8x8 matrix $H$ are orthogonal. In other words, $HH^T=8I_8$. Yet in other words, that's a Hadamard matrix. A curiosity following from that is that $4096$ is the maximum absolute value an 8x8 matrix of $\pm1$s can have. +1, of course.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for this. It looks very interesting that Hadamard matrix appears here. The remark about $4096$ also seems very interesting too.

Answer (score 4):

Here’s a sketch of a construction for a normal basis in this case, but I’m afraid it’s too late at night for me to go through all the details.

Let’s use the chain of field inclusions $\Bbb Q\subset k=\Bbb Q(i)\subset K=\Bbb Q(i,\lambda)$, where $\lambda^4=2$. Now if we’re just looking for a basis of $K$ over $\Bbb Q$, we know that we can take a (two-element) basis of $k$ over $\Bbb Q$ and a (four-element) basis of $K$ over $k$, and multiply them together element by element to get eight things that are $\Bbb Q$-linearly independent.

I propose to do the same thing with a normal basis of $K$ over $k$ and the well-known normal basis $\{1+i,1-i\}$ of $k$ over $\Bbb Q$. Roughy speaking, almost any random linear combination of all the basis elements of $K$ over $k$ should do the trick for the top layer of the chain, and I calculated the $4$-by-$4$ determinant for the four $k$-conjugates of $\mu=1+\lambda+2\lambda^2+4\lambda^3$, and found that this $\mu$ gave a normal basis. Remember that the Galois group is $\{e,\sigma,\sigma^2,\sigma^3\}$, where $\sigma(\lambda)=\lambda^\sigma=i\lambda$. That is, $\lambda^{\sigma^m}=i^m\lambda$.

Now I say that since $1+i$ gives a normal $\Bbb Q$-basis of $k$, and $\mu$ gives a normal $k$-basis of $K$, it’s fairly easy to see that $(1+i)\mu$ and its seven other conjugates under the total Galois group form a $\Bbb Q$-basis of $K$. It’s the details of this that I’m now too groggy to fill you in on.

Comment: (+1) Nice. Had I know this before writing my answer.. my calculations would have been so much simpler. In fact, I have $\mu = 1+\lambda + \lambda^2 + \lambda^3$.